# 'appMySortGrid' since it isn't a known property of 'div' for @directive is not working in angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I have created a new directive in angular Project for drag and drop functionality also declared in `app.module.ts` here is the my error

```
 src/app/modules/xyz.component.html:29:54 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'appMySortGrid' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

29                 [hidden]="isHidden(inputObj)" [appMySortGrid]="inputArray" draggable="true">
```

even I have checked typo's what will be the issue? how to fix this

//declared @directive in module

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MySortGridDirective } from './my-sort-grid.directive';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
       ...
        MySortGridDirective],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

//my-sort-grid.directive code

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appMySortGrid]'
})
export class MySortGridDirective {
    @Input() sortList: any;
}
```

//implementation of @directive in my component where i want to use it.

```
<div *ngFor="let inputObj of inputArray; [hidden]="isHidden(inputObj)" [appMnhSortGrid]="inputArray" draggable="true"> </div>
```

my @directive path is
`src\app\my-sort-grid.directive.ts`

how to fix this  issue 'appMySortGrid' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly using your directive.
You should write like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let inputObj of inputArray;" [hidden]="isHidden(inputObj)" appMySortGrid [sortList]="inputArray" draggable="true"> </div>
```

Comment: also is valid:`@Input('appMySortGrid') sortList: any;`